# bootstrap respionsive design collapse menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

i'm stuck. pleasw help. why my collapse menu button doesnt expand when pressed?
https://codepen.io/aalis/pen/egmmeW

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class=" navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My portfolio page</a>
    </div>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">My works</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What collapse menu button?  It isn't being displayed; how can it be pressed?

Comment: Everything works fine to me: https://jsfiddle.net/teutakoraqi/3edqu59q/3/, just be sure that you added javascript file first and than bootrap.js file.

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QdwyEW

You missed placing bootstrap js file in your pen.

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Add this in your javascript settings and it will work